# How do I connect as sysdba for oracle db using SQLALchemy

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy with flask
and I want to connect to oracle DB as sysdba

```
 SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI ='oracle+cx_oracle://sys:abc@DBNAME[mode=SYSDBA]'
```

This doesnt work and gives me a

```
 from flask import Flask  
 from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

 app = Flask(__name__)
 app.config.from_object('config')
 db = SQLAlchemy(app)   
 from app import views,models
```

and I use this db object later. But I am not able to figure out how to write the

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to login as sysdba

I also tried

```
CONN = cx_Oracle.connect('sys/abc', dsn='DBNAME', mode = cx_Oracle.SYSDBA)
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = CONN
```

But that also doesnt work.
 I get ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified” .. also If I remove mode=SYSDBA  I get ORA-28009 connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, should that code block be wrapped in backticks?

Answer (score 4):

Your `dsn` parameter is wrong. You must also separate the `user` and `password` parameters. Try this (it's working for me):

```
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('host', port, 'sid')
CONN = cx_Oracle.connect('sys', 'abc', dsn_tns, mode=cx_Oracle.SYSDBA)
```

For more info see [cx_Oracle.connect](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#cx_Oracle.connect) constructor.

Comment: Link appears to be dead. But your code example works. Yay! Only took 2 days, but I finally have `cx_Oracle` working.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: I am glad :) PS. The link has been updated and it's working now.